# Is product of G'AG semi positive definite? where G is hermitian matrix and A is positive definite

Tags: matrices, products, positive-definite

I have a question!

G is hermitian matrix and G' is it's hermitian

if A is positive definite,,,

Can we say G'AG is also positive definite?

I think it is but I need to prove this rigorously

help me

thanks!

Comment: It won't be positive definite if $G$ is singular.

Comment: What about if G is not singular?